# Transform Observable<any> to Observable<any[]>

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angularfire2, ngfor

iam working on an ionic3 app using the firebase real time database. Therefore i use [angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2). The app allows an user to store links. A link consists of an url and associated tags. This is how my database structure looks like:

[image: firebase database structure]

All links are located at `/links/`.
For an user the links are stored as referencing keys, located at `/users/this.user/links/`.

In the view i want to list all links of a certain user.
**Template detail:**

```
   <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items | async">
      <h3>{{item.url}}</h3>
      <!-- TODO: add tags and other meta information -->
    </ion-item>
```

This is what happens in the components constructor:

```
this.items = this.db.list('/users/' + this.user + '/links/')
    .flatMap(x => x)
    .flatMap(x => {
        let y: any = x;
        return this.db.list('/links/' + y.$key);
    })
    .map(res => {
        let url: string;
        let tags: string[] = [];

        for (let r of res) {

                // filter out tags
                if (r.$key === 'tags') {
                    for (let key in r)
                        if (key) tags.push(key);
                }

                // filter out url
                if (r.$key === 'url') {
                    for (let key in r) {
                        url = r[key];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } // for (let r of res)

        let link: Link = new Link(url, tags);
        return link;
    });

this.items.subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

This way my final observable emits the users link objects. The `console.log(res)` in the component subscription shows the desired result:

[image: component subscription console log]

But since i emit Link objects Angular tells me that ngFor only supports iterables:

[image]

Finally, my questions are:

1. How can i transform the `items` observable to something iterable by ngFor in the template?
2. Is there a better way of using rxjs operators to do my desired filtering?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Does the observable complete when it's finished emitting the items?

Comment: You are returning a `Link` object. Which array do you want to iterate? is it `tags`?

Comment: CozyAzure: I want a list of links, each link consisting of its url and its tags. Therfore i build the Link object to provide for my ngFor in the template. @ThinkingMedia I don't want the observable to finish since iam connected to a real time database and if a new link gets added my view must update, too.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you need to do it in Rx. I am assuming you want to get rid of all the data in the response and only get tags and url

```
const linkFromRaw = linkList => linkList
    .map(linkResponse => new Link(linkResponse.url, linkResponse.tags);

const linkToDetail = link => this.db.list('/links/' + link.$key))

this.items = this.db.list('/users/' + this.user + '/links/')
  .flatMap( links => Observable.forkJoin(links.map(linkToDetail))
     .reduce(
       (finalResponse, linkResponseArr) =>[...finalResponse, ...linkResponseArr],
       []
     )
  )
  .map(links => links.map(linkFromRaw));
```

Comment: Given two link references in `/users/this.user/links/` the **first flatMap** emits `[Object, Object]` of which each consists of `$value: true, $key:'linkReferenceKey'`, which is intended i guess, but the **second flatMap** emits a single empty array `[]`. Thus **map** doesn't receive anything.

Comment: Forgot a statement , can you try now with updated code

Comment: This solution does the same as mine above, but much cleaner. Thanks for that. The `toArray()` is all i need to transform my observable from `Link` to `Link[]`. But the actual problem is that `toArray()` doesn't emit anything. Adding `take(3)` right before the `toArray()` works perfectly fine, but only for the argument of 3 elements. Since i don't know how many items will arrive, how can i achieve `toArray()` to emit?

Comment: I had this doubt , how it will work . Thankyou , now I understand it won't work.  I will update the answer to make it work .

Comment: Can you try if this works. If it does not work, I will try myself in plnkr and provide you a working answer.

Comment: I can't make it work... Would be awesome if you provide a plnkr!!